# How can I create a separate NIB for each target?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller, nib

I have an iPhone app which finds nearby coffee shops, then displays the details (address, opening hours, WiFi availability) in a ShopViewController. I've created several other targets in the project (for example supermarket, restaurant) and each one has slightly different information to display in the ShopViewController. In the supermarket, I want to display whether alcohol is for sale. In the restaurant, I want to display last order times, and so on.

My current solution is not easy to maintain. I have a single shared NIB, with lots of `UILabel`s for every eventuality. Even though the coffee shops have no "last order" information, I use the same NIB with a "last order" `UILabel`. All my targets use a "title" label, but only one uses the "alcohol" label. I only use labels in the target(s) where they are necessary. The `UILabel`s are all set up with an empty string, and when I lay out the view, I ignore empty labels. But with 4 targets, it's getting hard to keep track.

My ShopViewController has some shared functionality, so I'm guessing that I should make subclasses, like CoffeeShopViewController, which inherit from the ShopViewController. Then I'd use an `#ifdef` to load the correct NIB for the current target. Then I could only include the relevant subclass in each target.

Is that the best solution, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one subclass for each of your different interfaces, you could have each subclass load the exact nib they want, avoiding the #if pre compiler statements.  But I think it will actually be simpler in the long run if you keep the one nib that gets used by each view controller subclass, and just keep the target-specific customization code in these subclasses.  Creating a bunch of nibs will only be useful to you if the customization you have to do to the nib is truly extensive.